# ¿Cómo limitar las opciones de un campo en filterView? Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Estoy haciendo una búsqueda de expedientes de un paciente y quiero filtrar por clinicas.

Para realizar la búsqueda utilizo una librería de Django llamada `django-filter` en la que te da una lista de todas las opciones posibles de los campos foreignkey.

Quiero filtrar los resultados del campo `fisio` con los fisios que pertenezcan al Usuario del grupo Clínica con el que estoy logeado ahora mismo.

Este es mi filtro:

```
class ExpedienteFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    paciente__nombre= django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    paciente__apellidos = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Abierto'),
        (1, 'Cerrado'),
    )


    class Meta:
        model = Expediente
        fields = ['fisio', 'estado', 'paciente__nombre', 'paciente__apellidos']
```

### Modelo Expediente

```
class Expediente(models.Model):
    paciente = models.ForeignKey(Paciente,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fisio = models.ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    patologia = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    f_apert = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    f_cierre = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    estado = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-f_apert"]
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.paciente)
```

El tema es que quiero que aparezcan solo los fisios que pertenecen a la clínica con la que estoy logueado ahora mismo pero me aparecen todas los fisios que existen.

Ejemplo:

Clinica 1 tiene fisio 1 y fisio 2 y clinica 2 tiene fisio 2 y fisio 3. Al entrar al expediente de un paciente de la clinica 1 quiero que en el select del filter me aparezcan solo fisio 1 y fisio 2.

Comment: clinica no tiene un modelo, es un grupo al que pertenecen los usuario. Actualizo la pregunta con el modelo de Expediente

Comment: No porque porque puedo tener dos fisios que tengan el mismo nombre y me aparecerian expedientes que no pertenecen a la clinica con la que está logueada en ese momento. Necesito que el select que me genera fisio se rellene solo con los fisios que están asociados a la clinica para poder realizar el filtro por esos fisios para encontrar el expediente que necesito.

Comment: Todos los modelos en Django tienen el campo id implicitos en la programación, no hace falta escribir ese campo.

Comment: Si no tienes modelo de Clínica, y es por grupo, basta una consulta a los usuarios que tengan permisos similares al fisio conectado, algo así: `User.objects.filter(user_permissions__in=self.request.user.user_permissions) | User.objects.filter(groups__in=self.request.user.groups)` y ser esos los que pongas en la lista, obviamente es mejor hacerlo con un objeto `Q` y unirlos en un `OR`. Y aplica lo mismo si consultas no desde la sesion, remplazas `self.request.user` por `expediente.fisio` sabiendo que `expediente` es una instancia de la clase `Expediente`

Comment: Creo que no se está entendiendo mi problema. Estoy usando una librería llamada django_filter que genera un formulario para buscar coincidencias en la base de datos y devolver una lista de objetos según la búsqueda que he hecho previamente. En dicho formulario me dan todas las opciones posibles dentro de los campos foreignkey de mi modelo, esas opciones son las que quiero delimitar de alguna forma. Completaré la pregunta con esta información.

Comment: otra opcion es usar el clasico raw sql de django pasas como parametro lo que deseas..

Comment: He conseguido solucionarlo modificando los modelos, era un problema de relación de los modelos. Gracias.